# Storm Twitter Access Key incorrect or missing

Tags: hadoop, twitter, apache-storm

When i am trying to run STORM Twitter code for fetch the data from online i am getting this error.

```
      [Wed May 10 18:25:45 PDT 2017]401:Authentication 
          credentials 
       (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. 
           Ensure that 
          you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and 
        the systemclock is in sync.
        <html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
        charset=utf-8"/>\n<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
           </head>
           <body>
           <h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
         <p>Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/filter.json'. Reason:
           <pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
          </body>
               </html>
```

anyone can tell me what i need to do for this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your Consumer key, Consumer secret, access token and access token secret have been written right.
2. This error can also occur if your system clock is not adjusted rightly.
3. Go to http://dev.twitter.com and check you have read and write privileges set for your application. If not set, set it and once again regenerate access keys.

Comment: i already did write and read permission for my application and my system clock is also right i checked again but still i am getting this error.